# Is a pull-up on open drain required when output is not used?

Tags: output, pullup, open-drain

On a LTC3886-1 I can read this:

[image]

I see that all open-drain outputs are tied to VDD on the following application schematics:

[image]

Is there a reason why pull-ups seem required when the output is not used?

Comment: Terminology clarification - those open-drain outputs are not 'tied to Vcc', they have pull-ups to Vcc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for one, there is a statement on the description of the pin itself (emphasis mine):

> SYNC (Pin 13): External Clock Synchronization Input and
> Open-Drain Output Pin. If an external clock is present
> at this pin, the switching frequency will be synchronized
> to the external clock. If clock master mode is enabled,
> this pin will pull low at the switching frequency with a
> 500ns pulse width to ground. **A resistor pull-up to 3.3V
> is required in the application.**

The pin can act as output and input. Based on that description leaving the pin floating might cause it to pick up noise and try to synchronize to that noise.

> The LTC3886 will automatically accept an external
> SYNC input, disabling its own SYNC drive if necessary.
> Whether configured to drive SYNC or not, the LTC3886
> can continue PWM operation using its own internal
> oscillator if an external clock signal is subsequently lost.
> The device can also be programmed to always require
> an external oscillator for PWM operation by setting bit 4
> of MFR_CONFIG_ALL_LTC3886. The status of the SYNC
> driver circuit is indicated by bit 10 of MFR_PADS.

So leaving it open sounds like it might cause some hick-ups in operation.